# How do I write a proper strcmp?

Tags: c

Below is the code I've written for `strcmp`, I want it to not differentiate between uppercase and lowercase letters, However it still does, How do I fix this?

```
int strcmp(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; str1[i] || str2[i];) {
        if (str1[i] > str2[i]) {
            int j = (str1[i] - str2[i]);
            if (j == 32)
                i++;
            else {
                return +1;
            }
        } else
        if (str1[i] < str2[i]) {
            int q = (str1[i] - str2[i]);
            if (q == -32) {
                i++;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else
        if (str1[i] == str2[i]) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:
Input:

```
Aryan
Semi
Kim
kim
Nap
```

Output:

```
Aryan
Kim
Nap
Semi
kim
```

Comment: `if ((isalpha(str1[i])?tolower(str1[i]):str1[i]) > etc`

Comment: So many branches... I recommend you just use to `toupper` or `tolower` on each character and compare *that*

Comment: Can you give a few examples of input and output? I'd guess that `if(j == 32)` is a bit too naïve. Consider `1` vs. `P` – these would count as equal!

Comment: `toupper` is benign when the character is not a lower case letter. So just compare `toupper(str[i])` with `toupper(str2[i])`.

Comment: dont use magic numbers like `32`. Also your code will fail even worse on systems where plain char is unsigned .

Comment: another problem is that you return `0` if the strings have different lengths, but match on the common substring.

Comment: It will return wrong result for many cases. E.g, "ab" is supposed to be less than "CD" but this func will return the opposite

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your function:

- do not name is `strcmp()`. You should not redefine standard functions with different semantics. `strcmp()` is usually highly optimized, it is possible that your version is not even the one used when you pass `strcmp` to your sorting function.
- The algorithm is incorrect: any 2 characters 32 positions apart are considered equal, for example "0" == "P".
- The comparison is non transitive: you have `"A" < "_"` and `"_" < "a"` yet `"A" == "a"`, which is very problematic for sorting.
- You should not assume ASCII and hard code the case offsets. Use `toupper()` from `<ctype.h>` and cast `char` values as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on negative values.
- `i` should be a `size_t`.
- `str1` and `str2` should be `const` qualified.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int strcmp_case(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    for (size_t i = 0;; i++) {
        int c1 = toupper((unsigned char)str1[i]);
        int c2 = toupper((unsigned char)str2[i]);
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return (c1 > c2) - (c1 < c2);
        }
        if (c1 == '\0') {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice and highly portable.  Detail (likely beyond OP's concern): Corner issue is in the case-less compare where a locale lacks a mapping of a lower case letter to upper.  Example [no traditional upper case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ẞ).  Pedantic code could use a round trip `int c1 = toupper(tolower((unsigned char)str1[i]));` or its cousin  `tolower(toupper())`.  The function order of those two tend to shift the sorting of `_` amongst   letters.

Comment: @chux: interesting article. It should be noted that when sorting German text , `ß` should expand to `ss`, which is probably beyond the OP's goals. Sorting French text is especially tricky as accents must be removed but still taken into account from right to left to distinguish words that differ only in accentuation.

Comment: The whole notion of a case-less compare is language/locale sensitive.  Certainly OP's initial coding foray here is introductory and your fine answer brings it up to the next level.  I'm just hoping for us all to move to UTF8, use a library function and settle on a universal case-less compare as the details of careless compares are extensive.

Comment: While this solution is definitely correct, seeing arithmetic operations on boolean values makes me feel uneasy. Harms the readability, IMHO.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Hmm, what do you suggest? `return c1 - c2;` which can have `int` overflow on select platforms?  `(c1 > c2) - (c1 < c2)` is very C idiomatic compare that avoids overflow issues for all(?) types of variables.

Comment: @chux There are many alternatives, of course. E.g., `return (c1 > c2) ? 1 : -1;` And `c1-c2` is incorrect semantically, BTW (regardless of the overflow)

Comment: @chqrlie The result of `(c1 > c2)` is boolean. You took 2 essentially boolean values, forced arithmetic operation on them and used the result to draw conclusions. It will compile, it will work but it is still wrong unless used in code obfuscation contest

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: boolean values such as `c1 > c2` have type `int` in C, there is no *forced arithmetic operation*. I understand you consider `(c1 > c2) - (c1 < c2)` hard to read and indeed it is surprising for beginners and non-native speakers, but it is idiomatic in C, like  `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.

Comment: @chqrlie I wasn't referring to overflow at all. I was talking exactly about what you wrote in your first comment. Yes, it's *technically* of type int and that's why the compiler has no problem. But semantics are of boolean and that's why I call it forced. Regarding idiomatic - it's idiomatic not in C but in certain environments (khm, Linux and like), doesn't mean it should be blindly followed. SW paradigms are also evolving, it's not 80's anymore.

Comment: @chqrlie I suppose I hurried up 4 years ago and wrote `c1 - c2` instead of `(c1 > c2) - (c1 < c2)`. Indeed in this way it misses the entire point since checking the numerical difference between 2 chars is perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
int strcasecmp(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; tolower((unsigned char)a[i]) == tolower((unsigned char)b[i]) && a[i]; ++i);
    return tolower((unsigned char)a[i]) - tolower((unsigned char)b[i]);
}
```

Comment: To have the exact match to the library `strcmp` the return value should be one of -1,0,1.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername No, it shouldn't. From man page: "The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2."